# Spark elasticsearch connector: how to select _id field?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I'm using the spark elasticsearch connector and I want to extract from ES some fields plus the _id.

```
myquery = """{"query":..., """
val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
                 .option("query", myquery)
                 .option("pushdown", "true")
                 .load("myindex/mytype")
                 .limit(10) 
                 .select("myfield","_id")
```

Unfortunately, the _id field is not recognized:

```
AnalysisException: u'cannot resolve \'`_id`\' given input columns: 
[query, size, @version, @timestamp, 
 sourceinfo, signaletic, document, metadata, fields, aggs]
```

With this mapping I can select for example document.{fieldA}, sourceinfo.{fieldB}, etc. but not _id. It's like if it's at a level to high in the mapping.

Any idea how to get this particular field?

Comment: i added an answer, do let me know if that helps you out. I was having the same problem. I hope the solution works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can access `_id` or the metadata by setting the [es.read.metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_metadata_when_reading_from_elasticsearch) to `True`

For example in your code:

```
myquery = """{"query":..., """
val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
                 .option("query", myquery)
                 .option("pushdown", "true")
                 .option("es.read.metadata",True) # Set it to True
                 .load("myindex/mytype")
                 .limit(10) 
                 .select("myfield","_id")
```

When you do

```
df.printSchema()
```

it will print something like ( in my case )

```
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_rt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_rt_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- username: string (nullable = true)
 |-- video: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _metadata: map (nullable = true) # this map column will be added
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

You can further extract the properties like
`_index`, `_type`, `_id`, `_score`, `sort` from _metadata column

To access the _id column from _metadata (map type) i have used this, you can use what you think best

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('temp_table_name')
spark.sql(""" 
     SELECT 
     _metadata._id as reference_id 
     FROM temp_table_name 
    """)
```

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score -1):

Some of the special characters like _,₹ not support in spark SQL.please try to replace the special characters with another character like "Id".

Comment: Thank you for your help @madhu but what do you mean by "try to replace"? I have no control on this elasticsearch naming (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html).